# Map not rendering. Only Grid lines are shown

Tags: java, android, kotlin, baidu, baidu-map

I am using Baidu Map (**SDK Version: 4.5.2**) but they the map is not showing. Instead, only grid lines are shown.

Code:

```
public class MainApp extends MultiDexApplication {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SDKInitializer.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

`BaiduMapActivity` class: (This code is in Kotlin. If you need Java equiavalent of this code, then please put a comment below.)

```
class BaiduMapActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_baidu_map)
    }

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    bmapView.onResume()
   }
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.2.10'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//For green dao
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
}

android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
    }

    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.emerson.oversight"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27

        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.6.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

kapt { generateStubs = true }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //AppCompat v7 support library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    //AppCompat v4 support library
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    //Support design
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    //Google Maps
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    //Retrofit - for making REST API calls
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //For Runtime permissions
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    //To set custom fonts
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    //Attaches bullets to viewpager
    compile 'com.robohorse.pagerbullet:pagerbullet:1.0.8'
    //Expandable recycler view
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
    //For Graph
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    //Date time
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6'
//    compile 'com.ncornette.cache:okcache-control:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.3'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.8.3'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'

    // notice that the compiler version must be the same than our gradle version
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha05'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Logs:

```
    03-27 23:44:51.059 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
03-27 23:44:51.062 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=113
03-27 23:44:51.062 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: setView = DecorView@dbaa2a1[BaiduMapActivity] touchMode=true
03-27 23:44:51.074 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight I/SemDesktopModeManager: registerListener: android.view.ViewRootImpl$3@1965e9e
03-27 23:44:51.076 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@a0e9d7f[BaiduMapActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
03-27 23:44:51.078 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=115
03-27 23:44:51.078 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@a0e9d7f[BaiduMapActivity]: setView = DecorView@6f71595[BaiduMapActivity] touchMode=true
03-27 23:44:51.079 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@52ebfdf[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(318, 2414 - 1122, 2568) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-27 23:44:51.102 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
03-27 23:44:51.127 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[37,1235][1403,1641] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 547931812352} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
    mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 547931812352} hwInitialized=true
03-27 23:44:51.135 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@a0e9d7f[BaiduMapActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
03-27 23:44:51.160 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@a0e9d7f[BaiduMapActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 547759640576} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
    mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 547759640576} hwInitialized=true
03-27 23:44:51.174 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/SurfaceView: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,393][1440,2792] result=0x7 surface={Surface(name=null)/@0x479929b isValid=true 547759644160}
03-27 23:44:51.221 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 547931812352}
03-27 23:44:51.233 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@a0e9d7f[BaiduMapActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 547759640576} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
03-27 23:44:51.237 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/SurfaceView: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,393][1440,2792] newFrame=[0,393][1440,2792] result=0x1 surface={Surface(name=null)/@0x479929b isValid=true 547759647744}
03-27 23:44:51.259 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(37, 1235 - 1403, 1641) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-27 23:44:51.262 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
03-27 23:44:51.263 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
03-27 23:44:51.264 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@a0e9d7f[BaiduMapActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=1
03-27 23:44:51.339 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ce7e452[SelectTripActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
03-27 23:44:51.359 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ce7e452[SelectTripActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
03-27 23:44:54.241 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@52ebfdf[Toast]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
03-27 23:44:54.247 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@52ebfdf[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
03-27 23:44:54.273 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=108
03-27 23:44:54.275 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight I/SemDesktopModeManager: unregisterListener: android.view.ViewRootImpl$3@c320e7e
03-27 23:44:59.878 7163-7168/com.emerson.oversight I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=114KB
03-27 23:44:59.880 7163-7168/com.emerson.oversight I/art: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=113KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
03-27 23:45:00.819 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ce7e452[SelectTripActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
03-27 23:45:00.874 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight I/CacheManager: TraxxEntity is null
03-27 23:45:01.533 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
03-27 23:45:01.534 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@ebc9b08[BaiduMapActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
03-27 23:45:01.572 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=113
03-27 23:45:01.575 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight I/SemDesktopModeManager: unregisterListener: android.view.ViewRootImpl$3@7f928ab
03-27 23:45:01.618 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/ViewRootImpl@a0e9d7f[BaiduMapActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 547759640576}
03-27 23:45:01.619 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@15fb381 nm : com.emerson.oversight ic=null
03-27 23:45:01.619 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
03-27 23:45:01.631 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=104
    Input channel destroyed: fd=103
03-27 23:45:01.631 7163-7163/com.emerson.oversight E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
```

Structure of libraries:

[image]

Result is below. Application is running perfectly but only Grid lines are shown and map is not visible.

[image]

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Can you check the logs and add relevant errors you might find there, to your question

Comment: @petey I have added logs.

Answer (score 0):

Several option can be the cause :

- No Api Key add in the Manifest
- Api Key bind to wrong SHA1, or wrong package name
- Use of the emulator. Based on my tests, never worked on emulator but worked perfectly on real devices (I bet on this one since i don't see communication error with baidu on your logs).

Answer (score 0):

Try using china vpn and then see if the maps are loaded